# Display entries based on 'entries fields'

Tags: relations, entries-field

I want to display blog entries within the related entry template linked together with 'entries fields':

```
-- Entrysection Bla

Blog
-- Blog entry 1 (Linked to Entrysection Bla via 'entries fields')
-- Blog entry 2 (no relations)
```

Now I want to display `Blog entry 1` in `Entrysection Bla`

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('bla') %}
  {% for entries_fields in craft.entries.section('blog'){# related to ??? #} %}
     <a href="{{ entries_fields.url }}">{{ entries_fields.title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I figured it has to be done with `relatedTo` but I cant get it done. How do I have to write this?

-- Edit:

Now my code on `Entrysection Bla` looks like this:

```
{% set entries_fields = craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo({
   sourceElement: entry,
   field: 'blogSaisonKategorie'
}) %}

{% for xy in entries_fields %}
   <a href="{{ xy.url }}">{{ xy.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

That prints out nothing. No error is displayed as well.

Comment: In your edit, where is `entry` coming from? Are you still doing the for loop around this code? Or are you relying on `entry` to be populated by Craft in how you're pointing to this template?

Comment: I changed `sourceElement` to `targetElement` now its bringing up all blog entries without filtering (It even shows the inactive blog entries). At least thats something. Yes I'm looping around the code. I guess my error has something to do with `targetElement: entry,`. It somehow does't listen to the fieldhandle of the `entries-fields` fiedltype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a huge mess and I started all over.

Thats the code which works:

```
      {# Gets the bla section #}
        {% for entry in craft.entries.section('bla') %}
          {# Gets the blog section related to bla #}
          {% set relatedBLogs = craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo(entry) %}
          {% for entries in relatedBLogs %}
             <a href="{{ entries.url }}">{{ entries.title }}</a>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

I thought I had to specify the entries fields but Craft determines the relational field without any declaration :O

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your assumption! Using [relatedTo](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) with the associated field:

```
{% set entries_fields = craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo({
    sourceElement: entry,
    field: 'fieldHandle'
}) %}
```

Note that `field` can be the field handle of your Entries Field but it can also be a field ID.

Comment: If I enter the fieldHandle of the 'field-entries' field there is still every entry displayed. I guess I have a mess between when to trigger the blog section and when the Bla section.

Comment: Are you entering `field-entries` as your field handle? I'm pretty sure that field handles can't have "hyphens" in them. `field-` is something that craft prepends. Go to Settings > Fields > Field Type and find the handle of your field. This is what you should enter in the example above